# jquery ajax callback Class variable is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, undefined

I would like to retrieve data from a file, and handle it, when its done.  My Class *DataService.js* is doing its job, but from outside, I cannot get to the loaded data. Below is my Code.

main.js

```
.
.
.
$('#loadMyData').on('click',function(event) {

    var m = dataService.loadLanguage().done(dataService.handleData);

    $.when(m).done(function() {
        console.log(dataService.loadedLanguage); // undefined
    });

});
.
.
.
```

DataService.js

```
class DataService {

    loadedLanguage;

    constructor() {
        this.loadedLanguage;
    }

    loadLanguage() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "php/services/readLanguage.php",
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            data: {data: "test"},
            dataTyp: 'json'
        });
    };

    handleData(data) {
        this.loadedLanguage = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(this.loadedLanguage); // ok
    }


}
```

Why is 'loadedLanguage' still undefined, even though its loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for $.when is like

```
$.when( { testing: 123 } ).done(function( x ) {
  alert( x.testing ); // Alerts "123"
});
```

You should write like this.

```
  $('#loadMyData').on('click',function(event) {

    var m = dataService.loadLanguage().done(dataService.handleData);

    $.when(m).done(function(responce) {
        console.log(responce); // You should catch response like this
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for that. But still, i can't get the 'loadedLanguage' via the object  from outside like this 'dataService.loadedLanguage'. Why is that?